# 2D Camera in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, camera, 2d

I am creating a top-down game in JavaFX, but I'm having trouble with the implementation of a Camera that moves with the player.

My attempt at creating something like this was to instead of moving the player, move the scene in the opposite direction the player wanted to go. This created the illusion that the player was moving, but it required constant movement of *all* the objects in the scene which obviously created a ton of performance issues. So after this I made a clip, and put all the terrain nodes inside a clipped rectangle.

Below is my `TerrainRenderer` class that creates the clipped rectangle and the contents inside of it. What it does is take an image and then generate a bunch of rectangle nodes in order to make a map that looks like the image.

```
private static final Pane tileContainer = new Pane();
private static final Rectangle rectClip = new Rectangle();

private static void clipChildren(Region region) {
    region.setClip(rectClip);
    region.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        rectClip.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
        rectClip.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
    });
}

private static void drawTile(int x, int y, Color color) {
    final int TILE_SIZE = 15;
    Rectangle tile = new Rectangle(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    tile.setFill(color);
    tileContainer.getChildren().add(tile);
}

public static Region generate() {
    final Image map = new Image("main/Images/IcJR6.png");
    for (int x = 0; x < (int) map.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < (int) map.getHeight(); y++) {
            drawTile(x, y, map.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y));
        }
    }
    tileContainer.setPrefSize(Main.getAppWidth(), Main.getAppHeight());
    clipChildren(tileContainer);
    return tileContainer;
}

public static Rectangle getRectClip() {
    return rectClip;
}
```

What you see below is my update method for the player that uses a sprite sheet. As of now this code only translates the clip node, but not the contents inside.

```
void update() {
    int speed;
    if (Main.isPressed(KeyCode.SHIFT)) speed = 6;
    else speed = 3;
    if (Main.isPressed(KeyCode.W)) {
        getAnimation().play();
        getAnimation().setOffsetY(96);
        moveY(speed);
    } else if (Main.isPressed(KeyCode.S)) {
        getAnimation().play();
        getAnimation().setOffsetY(0);
        moveY(-speed);
    } else if (Main.isPressed(KeyCode.D)) {
        getAnimation().play();
        getAnimation().setOffsetY(64);
        moveX(-speed);
    } else if (Main.isPressed(KeyCode.A)) {
        getAnimation().play();
        getAnimation().setOffsetY(32);
        moveX(speed);
    } else getAnimation().stop();
}

@Override
protected void moveX(int x) {
    boolean right = x > 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.abs(x); i++) {
        if (right) TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().setTranslateX(TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().getTranslateX() + 1);
        else TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().setTranslateX(TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().getTranslateX() - 1);
    }
}

@Override
protected void moveY(int y) {
    boolean down = y > 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(y); i++) {
        if (down) TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().setTranslateY(TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().getTranslateY() + 1);
        else TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().setTranslateY(TerrainRenderer.getRectClip().getTranslateY() - 1);
    }
}
```

The result I want would look something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdVTyWDHhWM) (skip to 6:10), but how would I make something like this in JavaFX instead? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can draw the entire thing first, just define a [`clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty), and move it along with the `translateX` and `translateY` properties.

Comment: What would my code look like? The code I have right now only translates the player, so would I add a clip to the pane in the scene? `pane.getClip().setTranslateY(pane.getClip().getTranslateY() - 1);` for moving the pane up one pixel?

Comment: Create a rectangle for the clip, bind its x and y properties to functions of the translateX and translateY properties of the player. (You might want to bind the width and height to the width and height of the display, or just hard code them.).

Comment: I apologize as I am new to using clips, but what would clipping a rectangle and binding its X Y properties to the translate properties of the player do? Why would this be a better solution that wouldn't create lag?

Comment: A clip restricts the portion of a node that is rendered.

Comment: Ok, I found the time to finish the clip, and my code is updated now. So all the contents are clipped into a rectangle and that part works fine, but how do i move the shapes inside the clip rectangle instead of the clip rectangle itself? I tried using X and Y instead of translateX and translateY but it gave the same result except laggier than using translate.

Comment: Yeah, not really clear from your little code snippets what you are doing. I posted a [MCVE] that shows the approach I had in mind; it seems to perform just fine. If your code is not performing well, you need to narrow down the problem and post a complete example (complete but < 200 lines) that shows the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted a minimal, complete, and verifiable example showing what the actual problem is, so your question is difficult to answer completely.

I would approach something like this by drawing the background (e.g. on a canvas), and putting it in a pane with the moving parts (player, by the sounds of your description). Then show just a portion of the background by clipping and translating the pane.

Here's a very quick example; it just puts some random small rectangles on a large canvas and then moves a blue rectangle (player) around the scene on pressing the cursor (arrow) keys. The clip and translation of the main pane are bound to the player's position so the player always appears in the center, except when you get close to the edges of the pane.

This takes a little time to start up, and for some reason I sometimes see a blank screen until I have moved the player a couple of places; I didn't spend too much time on niceties so there may be some little bugs in there.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollAndClipBackground extends Application {

    private final int tileSize = 10 ;
    private final int numTilesHoriz = 500 ;
    private final int numTilesVert = 500 ;

    private final int speed = 400 ; // pixels / second
    private boolean up ;
    private boolean down ;
    private boolean left ;
    private boolean right ;

    private final int numFilledTiles = numTilesHoriz * numTilesVert / 8 ;   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = createBackground();
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(numTilesHoriz*tileSize/2, numTilesVert*tileSize/2, 10, 10);
        player.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        pane.getChildren().add(player);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(pane), 800, 800);
        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
        clip.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        clip.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());

        clip.xProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> clampRange(player.getX() - scene.getWidth() / 2, 0, pane.getWidth() - scene.getWidth()), 
                player.xProperty(), scene.widthProperty()));
        clip.yProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> clampRange(player.getY() - scene.getHeight() / 2, 0, pane.getHeight() - scene.getHeight()), 
                player.yProperty(), scene.heightProperty()));

        pane.setClip(clip);
        pane.translateXProperty().bind(clip.xProperty().multiply(-1));
        pane.translateYProperty().bind(clip.yProperty().multiply(-1));

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> processKey(e.getCode(), true));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> processKey(e.getCode(), false));

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            private long lastUpdate = -1 ;
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate ;
                if (lastUpdate < 0) {
                    lastUpdate = now ;
                    return ;
                }
                double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                double deltaX = 0 ;
                double deltaY = 0 ;
                if (right) deltaX += speed ;
                if (left) deltaX -= speed ;
                if (down) deltaY += speed ;
                if (up) deltaY -= speed ;
                player.setX(clampRange(player.getX() + deltaX * elapsedSeconds, 0, pane.getWidth() - player.getWidth()));
                player.setY(clampRange(player.getY() + deltaY * elapsedSeconds, 0, pane.getHeight() - player.getHeight()));
                lastUpdate = now ;
            }
        };

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        timer.start();
    }

    private double clampRange(double value, double min, double max) {
        if (value < min) return min ;
        if (value > max) return max ;
        return value ;
    }

    private void processKey(KeyCode code, boolean on) {
        switch (code) {
        case LEFT: 
            left = on ;
            break ;
        case RIGHT: 
            right = on ;
            break ;
        case UP:
            up = on ;
            break ;
        case DOWN:
            down = on ;
            break ;
        default:
            break ;
        }
    }

    private Pane createBackground() {

        List<Integer> filledTiles = sampleWithoutReplacement(numFilledTiles, numTilesHoriz * numTilesVert);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(numTilesHoriz * tileSize, numTilesVert * tileSize);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        Pane pane = new Pane(canvas);

        pane.setMinSize(numTilesHoriz * tileSize, numTilesVert * tileSize);
        pane.setPrefSize(numTilesHoriz * tileSize, numTilesVert * tileSize);
        pane.setMaxSize(numTilesHoriz * tileSize, numTilesVert * tileSize);

        for (Integer tile : filledTiles) {
            int x = (tile % numTilesHoriz) * tileSize ;
            int y = (tile / numTilesHoriz) * tileSize ;
            gc.fillRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
        }

        return pane ;
    }

    private List<Integer> sampleWithoutReplacement(int sampleSize, int populationSize) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        List<Integer> population = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < populationSize; i++) 
            population.add(i);
        List<Integer> sample = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < sampleSize ; i++) 
            sample.add(population.remove(rng.nextInt(population.size())));
        return sample;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A more complex approach, which would be less memory intensive, would be a "tiling" mechanism where the main view consists of a number of tiles which are moved, and created as needed on demand. This is more complex but allows for essentially arbitrary-sized scenes.